# using beautifulsoup to scrape html error "div" not defined

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract information under div class, but when I use the code the message appears "div" not defined. The soup works fine, and I see that there are lots of divs in side, what could be the problem?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for item in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content"}):
        print(div.find("a")['href'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div` variable was actually never defined, you meant to use `item` instead:

```
for item in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "article-content"}):
    print(item.find("a")['href'])  # or item.a['href']
```

Or, you can get to the links directly with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for a in soup.select("div.article-content a"):
    print(a['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually figured it after staring at it for some minutes, yes now I understand that it should be div not item